# Filtering an array under the forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```js
const likedUsers = [{
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
  }
]
const needToFilter = [{
    id: "1",
    userInfo: "info"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    userInfo: "info"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    userInfo: "info"
  }
]
likedUsers.forEach(item => needToFilter.filter(needToFilter => {
  return needToFilter.id !== item.id
}));
console.log(users);
```

I have two arrays like that and if needToFilter array's user id exist in likedUsers array it need to be gone.

Filtered array be like :

```
needToFilter => [{id:"3",userInfo:"info"}]
```

I tried `forEach` and `map` but result is the same. I know there is another way but i can't figure out how.
Thank you all guys.

Edit :
All the answers works great in my case but i used Set approach to fix my problem.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you have an array called liked and an array called needToFilter. You want to remove all entries from the array that are not in the likedUsers ... correct?

Comment: Where do you assign `users`?

Comment: Instead of filter use ```some``` and return true when you find the matching value exit it

Comment: Or you need the needToFilter array to have only unique elements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could create a [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the `likedUsersIds` before filtering:

```js
const likedUsers = [
  {
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
  }
];

const needToFilter = [
  {
    id: "1",
    userInfo: "info"
  }, 
  {
    id: "2",
    userInfo: "info"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    userInfo: "info"
  }
];

const likedUsersIds = new Set(likedUsers.map(o => o.id));
const filtered = needToFilter.filter(o => !likedUsersIds.has(o.id));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of `needToFilter.filter()` to `users`.

The filtering function can use `some()` to test whether there's any match in `likedUsers`.

```js
const likedUsers = [{
    id: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
  }
]
const needToFilter = [{
    id: "1",
    userInfo: "info"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    userInfo: "info"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    userInfo: "info"
  }
]

const users = needToFilter.filter(n => !likedUsers.some(l => l.id == n.id));
console.log(users);
```

Comment: Very brilliant thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

```
users = needToFilter.filter(a=> !likedUsers.find(i=> i.id == a.id))
```

EDIT:

Adding detailed answer so that i can be in same team:

You could use [MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store liked users then filter if not found in map:

```js
const likedUsers = [
    {
        "id":"1"
    },
    {
        "id":"2"
    }
];

const needToFilter = [
    {
        "id":"1",
        "userInfo":"info"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "userInfo":"info"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "userInfo":"info"
    }
];

const mp = new Map();
    
likedUsers.forEach(i=>mp.set(i.id,true));

const users = needToFilter.filter(i => !mp.has(i.id));
console.log(users)
```

Tip: Benefit of Map, complexity will be O(n) instead of O(n^2)